# How to get more than 1000 Kicked Users with Telethon

Tags: telegram-bot, telethon

I had a Telegram group with 3000 members. I lost 2500 members. I want to get the username of all them. I tried with this code, but the method just fetch 1000 items and no more. How could I fetch the other 1500 users?

```py
import os
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
from telethon.tl.types import ChannelParticipantsKicked

api_id = os.getenv('TELEGRAM_API')
api_hash = os.getenv('TELEGRAM_HASH')
chat = -123456789
client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)

async def main():
    await client.start()
    async for user in client.iter_participants(chat, filter=ChannelParticipantsKicked):
        # Do something with the data

with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: There's an `limit` option on the `iter_participants`, try setting it to higher then 100

Comment: No, doesn´t work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can not fetch more than 1000 members with `iter_participants`

look at this [issue on Github](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/issues/3708)